# Compiling cairo (cairomm) on Windows

Tags: c++, compilation, cairo

I'm trying to compile cairo into a lib file using Mingw. I've downloaded the cairo, cairomm, and pixman source packages, but I can't figure out where to go from here. The INSTALL help file talks about a bunch of scripts that I can't seem to run or even find ('./configure', 'make', 'make install'). Googling the issue is bringing up nothing helpful.

I feel like this is a noobish question to ask. I've only recently started getting into the C++ side of programming (coming from Java/C#), and this is the first time I've had to compile an external library before using it. The shocking lack of explanations on the process makes me wonder if there was some chapter of a tutorial somewhere I was supposed to read that makes this whole process a complete no-brainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this project isn't supporting building with Mingw.

There are build instructions here for building with Visual Studio (which can be downloaded for free as the Visual Studio Express Edition from MS Website: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs

Build instructions here:
http://cairographics.org/end_to_end_build_for_win32/

It's probably possible to make this work for MingW, but you will have to make it work yourself, which may be a bit of a long step for someone who is new to compilers and build scripts in general.

Comment: I followed those instructions, and they worked great up until I had to compile pixman. When I tried that, I got: 
`Setting MMX flag to default value 'on'... (use MMX=on or MMX=off)
Setting SSE2 flag to default value 'on'... (use SSE2=on or SSE2=off)
Setting SSSE3 flag to default value 'on'... (use SSSE3=on or SSSE3=off)
pixman.c
c:\users\------\buildcairo\pixman\pixman\pixman-private.h(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'float.h': No such file or directory
make: *** [release/pixman.obj] Error 2`